# Change vibrate mode after return time difference(in min) in Android

Tags: java, android

I want to change the vibrate mode to general mode after a certain time difference. .I am able to change mode but i am getting difficulty in continuously checking current time with the end time. I have done this

```
try {
    long store = compareEndTime(diff);

    for (int i = 1; i <= store; i++) {
        am.setRingerMode(2);//for normal mode
    }
catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I want a something which check the time automatically after each minute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) for check every minute what you want

This is a sample:

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            int minute = 1;
            @Override
            public void run() {
                {
                    //do something...
                    long delay = minute * 60000;                        
                    handler.postDelayed(this,delay);
                }
            }
        }, 0);
```

Hope it helps!